# Trying to play a sound file using c# open source managed operating system (cosmos) project in visual studio

Tags: cosmos

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Media.SoundPlayer;
```

---

Since cosmos uses c#, I am trying to use System.Media.SoundPlayer to play a sound file, but visual studio shows a red squiggle under "Media", saying "The type or namespace doesn't exist in the namespace 'System'(are you missing an assembly reference)". How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, SoundPlayer is not a namespace, its the class name.
So you can just import the media namespace and use the SoundPlayer like below.

`using System.Media;`

and in code, use like this:

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer (@"###.mp3");
player.Play();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the method you suggested but visual studio is still showing a red squiggle under "Media"

Comment: Oops, I think its a .Net core project and may not have support. Could you please check whether this SO question is helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845506/how-to-play-a-sound-in-netcore