# Does .Net 5 support any ways to play/make sounds on Mac platform?

Tags: macos, .net-5

I've recently started using .Net 5 on Mac, and I've discovered that `Console.Beep` throws an 'unsupported operation' exception.
Do the standard libraries provide a working way to make sounds for Mac? I do not believe they did in .Net Core, as per: [How to play a sound in NETCore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845506/how-to-play-a-sound-in-netcore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: From further research, I believe the answer is NO.

I discovered the `System.Media.SoundPlayer` class (which [is in .Net 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=net-5.0)), but I got a compile error System.Media belonged to missing assembly `System.Windows.Extensions`.
I found and installed this via Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Extensions/

My application now compiled but upon trying to call `SoundPlayer.Play()` I got `PlatformNotSupportedException` -
"System.Windows.Extensions types are not supported on this platform."

I can't see in the documentation anywhere if .Net 6.0 will change this though.